# Перебор элементов списка

Tags: python

Существует ли боллее рациональный способ перебрать все возможные списки из 5 элементов, которые взяты(элементы) из другого списка. Начальный список имеет немало элементов (от 100 до 300), поэтому мой способ очень медленный.

```
for i1 in lst[:-4]:
    for i2 in lst[lst.index(i1)+1:-3]:
        for i3 in lst[lst.index(i2)+1:-2]:
            for i4 in lst[lst.index(i3)+1:-1]:
                for i5 in lst[lst.index(i4)+1:]:
                    result.append([i1, i2, i3, i4, i5])
```

Comment: А что если их будет 200 - 300 или более, вы будете 300 циклов писать?

Comment: Мне нужно перебрать один список. Так- то я и спрашиваю альтернативу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itertools.combinations(iterable, [r])` - [комбинации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) длиной r из iterable без повторяющихся элементов.

```
>>> print list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3], 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```